# Homestead up conflicts with the VM it created

Tags: laravel, homestead

I am progressively updating files to get rid of errors to get laravel setup.

I am now running into this error when i run `homestead up`

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
←[K==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
A VirtualBox machine with the name 'homestead' already exists.
Please use another name or delete the machine with the existing
name, and try again.
```

I opened Virtualbox but couldnt find any VM's so after some research I ran `vagrant golbal-status` and destroyed any VM's with `vagrant destroy <VM id>`

This didnt seem to work so I manually deleted the .vagrant folder from the Homestead directory and retried.

After the error, when I run `vagrant global-status` again it shows the VM that is created, so its as if homestead creates the machine and then tried to recreate it? hence the conflict. This is the second day of trying to get laravel going, im on windows 8.1 T^T

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue.The following fixed it for me.
from the terminal run the command

$vagrant global-status

the output was

### id       name    provider   state    directory

74c92a7  default virtualbox poweroff /home/maiko/.composer/vendor/laravel/homestead 
e73c724  default virtualbox poweroff /home/maiko/Desktop/code/Homestead

what i did was delete the hometead instance of 74c92a7

$vagrant destroy 74c92a7

once i ran vagrant up again everything went smooth.

hope that helps